# call an JSP Page inside my JSP Page with Parameter

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I Have a main JSP page called **Main.jsp**

where from sidebar need to call a **inner.jsp** with a Parameters

used `<jsp:include page="inner.jsp" flush="true" />`

but need to set parameter like `inner.jsp?id=''_&tableID=''`

while clicking the link from sidebar menu as `<a onclick=''>test1</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<jsp:param>` tag:

```
<jsp:include page="${page}">
<jsp:param value="${canale}" name="channel"/>
</jsp:include>
```

in the included page you may:

```
<c:if test='${not empty param.channel}' >
<input type='hidden' name='canale'  value="${param.channel}">
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks , it give me nice lead in understanding <jsp: Param> . but now i need to change the param on clicking sidebar link and it should load the inner jsp with new param

Comment: @AzizShaikh: that's a different beast, you will need some client side javascript and definitely you won't be able to use include, all jsp: tags are "resolved" server side, before the page is actually sent to your browser, you will have to put in some sort of post to the server (e.g. via ajax) and change the content of the page via js.